# flask send base 64 encoded pdf string without saving

Tags: python, flask, selenium-webdriver, pdf, http-headers

I have a flask application. I am using selenium cdp commands to generate pdfs. I get a base64 encoded string from selenium. Before sending the response as a pdf I save the file in my filesystem.

```
file.write(base64.b64decode(pdf_string['data'])
```

And the response is just `send_file('path', 'name.pdf')`

How do i serve the pdf without saving it to a file. I was trying to look for a BytesIO solution but I don't fully understand it yet.
I also tried setting the mimetype / header to 'application/pdf' and 'application/pdf;base64'

type of decoded string is 'bytes'
and type of pdf_string['data'] is 'str'

Is there a way I can accomplish this without saving files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are on right track to figuring out that saving a pdf and again reading it is not a great solution.

Instead, use ByteIO as follows:

```
pdf_bytes = base64.b64decode(pdf_string['data'])

pdf = BytesIO()
pdf.write(pdf_bytes)
pdf.seek(0)
```

and then use send_file

This is very similar to ByteBuffer implementation in Java. seek method as the name suggest seeks/resets the pointer to the first byte.

Let me know if this works, Thanks.

Comment: This works thanks. The one liner mentioned in another answer also works. 'pdf_io = BytesIO(pdf_bytes) ' i'll be using that

Comment: for sure, just overloaded methods. Glad this worked.